# I keep getting this ERROR: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports

Tags: html, json, angular, components

I keep getting this error and I don't know what to do:
**ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays**

this is my service

```
 recupererHistorique(idCitoyen:number): Observable<Historique[]>{ 

    let url = 'http://localhost/tpSyn/getHistoriqueCitoyen.php?idCitoyen=' + idCitoyen;
    return this.http.get<Historique[]>(url); 
  }
```

this is the component

```
export class HistoriqueComponent implements OnInit {

  
 @Input() historiquee:Historique;
 historique: Historique[]; 
 selectionActive:boolean = true;
 
  constructor(private serviceCovid: CovidTraceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  surChangementCitoyen(){
    
  //this.historiquee = null;
  

  }

  
  surChangementHistorique(his: Historique){
    this.serviceCovid.recupererHistorique(his.id).subscribe(histo => this.historique = histo);
    
  
  }
 
}
```

And the HTMl

```
  <section *ngIf="historiquee" >
    
    <div >
        <ol >
            <li *ngFor='let hiss of historiquee'> {{hiss.date}}: {{hiss.description}} </li>
        </ol>
    </div>

     
    </section>
```

In the HTML if i use this instead it works but it shows one line and i want it to show all of the other lines thats why i want to use a *ngFor

```
  <div>
            <ol>
                <h3>
                    <li> {{historiquee.date}}: {{historiquee.description}} </li>
                </h3>

            </ol>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: There is nothing in the array. Hide the ngFor until after data is there.

Comment: how do i hide it?

Comment: Can you `console.log` and show what is the type of your historiquee. It looks like it's a `{date: 1, description: 2}` kind of object. It should be a `[ ... ]`

Comment: when i console.log it says Undefined

Answer (score 1):

ngFor can only iterate over an array, It means that the result has to be an array! it cannot be undefined or null which are not iterable.

so when using ngFor you need to have either an empty array or a populated array.

Make sure your service properly returns an array by console loggin' the result.

`this.serviceCovid.recupererHistorique(his.id).subscribe(histo => console.log(histo));`

If your service may return undefined compare your value to an empty array.

`historique: Historique[] = [];`

Comment: when i console.log it it shows [ ] @Aviad

Comment: try to initialize the value with empty array and see if it solves the problem
historique: Historique[ ] = [ ];

Comment: can you post the returned value ? 
It seems you're trying to access an object key inside an array.
did you make sure you always get the keys date and description?

Comment: this is the data that i want to return [
{
"id": "482",
"dateInfec": null,
"idCitoyen": "2952",
"description": "en test",
"date": "2020-11-01"
},
{
"id": "483",
"dateInfec": null,
"idCitoyen": "2952",
"description": "neutre",
"date": "2020-11-06"
}
]

Comment: try to console log the next thing and make sure you get the same result :
```    this.serviceCovid.recupererHistorique(his.id).subscribe(histo => 
{this.historique = histo; console.log(this.historique)}) ```;
validate the you array is stored properly.

Answer (score 0):

ok it worked
i had the wrong id it his.idCitoyen not his.id

```
 surChangementHistorique(his: Historique){
    this.serviceCovid.recupererHistorique(his.idCitoyen).subscribe(histo => this.historique = histo);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngFor` only supports Iterables such as `Array`, so you cannot use it for `Object`.